# Set Cookie header in request in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, cookies

I'm making an app in flutter with web support where some endpoints require a cookie value with info of the user. The problem is when i pass the header `Cookie: ...` in web I get the following error.

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"
```

The same code in others platforms works fine. How can i fix this?

Comment: `Cookie` is one of the [forbidden header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name), when it comes to making requests using client-side JavaScript in the browser - _"the name of any HTTP header that cannot be modified programmatically; specifically, an HTTP request header name. [...] Modifying such headers is forbidden because the user agent retains full control over them."_